# jQuery Isotope - Not working within a responsive/fluid grid

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-masonry, responsive-design, jquery-isotope

I am in the process of building a photoblog which utilises the brilliant Isotope plugin by David DeSandro but I am curently having some difficulty getting the plugin to work as intended within a responsive / fluid grid.

www.lewismalpas.co.uk/tumblr (Demo)

Each image is wrapped within a div (.item) which has an explicit width of 25%, as the images are flexible this in theory should allow four images to be displayed inline, however at the moment only two are being displayed and I cannot seem to figure out the issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

//scroll to top of page
$("a.top").click(function () {
    $("body,html").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 800);
    return false;
});

//Isotope settings
var $container = $('.images')
$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
    $container.isotope({
        resizable: false, // disable normal resizing
        masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 4 }
    });
    // update columnWidth on window resize
    $(window).smartresize(function(){
        $container.isotope({
            masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 4 }
        });
    });
});

//layout & search options
$(".header #layout").hide();
$(".header a.layout").click(function() {
    $(".header #layout").fadeIn();

    $(".header a.fullscreen").click(function() {
        $("a.layout-option").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $("#container").animate({width:"99%"}, function() {
            $(".images").isotope('reLayout');
        });
    });
    $(".header a.grid").click(function() {
        $("a.layout-option").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $("#container").animate({width:"80%"}, 800);
        $('#images').isotope({itemSelector:'.item',layoutMode:'masonry'});
    });
    $(".header a.linear").click(function() {
        $("a.layout-option").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $("#container").animate({width:"80%"}, 800);
        $('#images').isotope({itemSelector:'.item',layoutMode:'straightDown'});
    });
});

$(".header #search").hide();
$(".header a.search").click(function() {
    $(".header #search").fadeIn();
});

}); //end doc ready
</script>
```

Comment: I reduced the width of .item by .5% which seemed to fix a lot of the errors I was experiencing as apparently Isotope was rounding up somewhere which was breaking the layout!